# MLT Framework. How to speed up video?

Tags: ffmpeg, mlt

Need to speed up video with MLT.
I can do it with ffmpeg:

```
-filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS"
```

But what about MLT?

Answer (score 1):

The "timewarp" producer in MLT can change the video speed.

https://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/ProducerTimewarp

To double the speed (play faster) use:

```
$ melt timewarp:2.0:file.mp4
```

To half the speed (play slower) use:

```
$ melt timewarp:0.5:file.mp4
```

To speed up part of the file, you would have to split it up with in/out points:

```
$ melt file.mp4 in=0 out=29 timewarp:2.0:file.mp4 in=60 out=238 file.mp4 in=120
```

Notice that the in/out points need to be scaled by the speed factor when applied to the timewarp producer.

Comment: how can i speed up only part of video? from 30 to 120 frame for example

Comment: Tried to run: 
melt "/path/21.mp4"  timewarp:2.0:"/path/22.mp4"  -mix 7 -mixer luma "/path/25.mp4" -mix 7 -mixer luma
Got an error: Failed to load "timewarp:2.0/path/22.mp4"

What i did wrong?

Comment: Also tried: melt 2.0:Finish.mov -profile atsc_720p_2997 -consumer avformat:"Out.mp4" it shows no error, but video speed is the same

Comment: timewarp:2.0:file.mp4 - produces just white screen... 
melt 21.mp4 in=0 out=15 "timewarp:2.0:21.mp4" in=15 out=45 21.mp4 in=45 -consumer avformat:"out.mp4" vcodec=libx264 vb=5500k ab=128k strict=-2
Produced video: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o6t965qcvy9tuz/out2.mp4?dl=0